# How to calculate total availability based on individual object availabilities?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, uptime, availability

How to calculate overall availability given individual object availability percentages?

Example 1: I have sql server with FCI.

VM1 has 99.9% availability

VM2 has 99.9% availability

What is total availability calculation?

Example 2: same as above plus disk storage has 99.9% availability. So what is total availability?

Example 3: Suppose I have 1 VM and 1 disk storage. Each with 99.9% availability. So what is total availability calculation?

Comment: Confused due to the 2 answers

Answer (score 1):

AWS is using [Calculating Total System Availability](http://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/architecture/CalculatingTotalSystemAvailability.pdf) article for  availability calculation. So in your setup you have to recognize what is **parallel** and what is **serial** relationships. For basic scenarios:

**Serial Configuration**

```
A(VM1 + disk) = 0.999 * 0.999 = 0.998
```

**Parallel Configuration**

Assuming VM2 is a redundancy for VM1

```
A(VM1, VM2) = 1 - (1-0.998)(1-0.998) = 0.99996
```

Answer (score 0):

Example 1: If you have 2 VMs and each one has 99.9% availability and your total availability like below

.999 * .999 = .998 it means monthly 1h 27m 39s of downtime.

Example 2: If you have 2 VMs and each one has 99.9% availability and one more disk storage has 99.9% availability. your total availability like below

.999 * .999* .999=.997 it means monthly 2h 11m 29s of downtime.

Example 3: if you have 1 VM and 1 disk storage. Each with 99.9% availability and your total availability like below

.999* .999=.998 it means monthly 1h 27m 39s of downtime.

The [SLA](https://cloud.google.com/terms/sla/) for Google cloud VMs when you have two or more VMs configured across various availability zones is 99.99%.

You can also use this [link](https://clusteringformeremortals.com/2020/07/24/calculating-application-availability-in-the-cloud/) for compute engine and storage availability and use [link](https://uptime.is/) for SLA calculations,